# Multiple NICs, Multiple Gatways (public and private)

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, static-ip

Apologies in advance for re-asking a question that's been posted several times.  I've attempted to follow previous guides, but seem to be getting fairly stuck!  Running Ubuntu 16.04, I have a public facing network (192.99.110.188) and a private network (10.16.110.188).  Users need to be able to access from the private network, but the public network is necessary for updates and running backups to crashplan.

The contents of my /etc/network/interfaces file is:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
       address 192.99.110.188
       netmask 255.255.255.192
       broadcast 192.99.110.191
       gateway 192.99.110.129
       dns-nameservers 192.99.203.20 192.99.25.14

auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
       address 10.16.110.188
       netmask 255.255.255.192
       post-up ip route add 10.16.0.0/24 dev eth1 src 10.16.110.188 table rt2
       post-up ip route add default 10.16.110.188 via 10.16.110.129 dev eth1 table rt2
       post-up ip rule add from 10.16.110.188/32 table rt2
       post-up ip rule add to 10.16.110.188/32 table rt2
```

And the routing table (route -n) looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         137.99.110.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.16.110.128   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1
192.99.110.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

I've been fiddling with the setup for a while, but to be safe, I have been running on just the private network (so users can access things).  When I then enable the public interface (eth0), the system seems to work for a few hours, and then the private interface stops responding - cue the angry user emails.

Any help would be much appreciated!